# Google Analytics - gtag property

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics, gtag.js

I have one GA account and multiple GA property in that account. The question, what's the Ideal set up in adding gtag? I know that each property has its own gtag code, so, should I use each gtag code and adde them in every webpage? The weird thing is, previous landing pages use one gtag code and it worked before in all the properties.

info.example.com
 (Account)

info.example.com
 (property)

info.example.co.uk
 (property)

info.example.hk (property)

Answer (score 1):

Surely the **tracking code must be present on all pages**, then it depends on how you want to track. You can do it all within the same Property or in separate Properties.